# Passing the clicked button's ID as a parameter in a function (Angular 10.1.6)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a button with a set ID I need to pass as a parameter. I've tried doing it like this:

```
<span class="nav-link btn btn-white btn-animate" id="{{prov.provname}}" (click)="getProvCustomers(this.id)">{{prov.provname}}</span>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried searching through the official Angular documentation with no luck. I feel as if I'm missing something plainly obvious here.

Comment: Like this ? `<id="{{prov.provname}}" (click)="getProvCustomers(prov.provname)"`

Comment: I knew it was obvious :( Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try in Two ways

1. if you have id property in Template,

Then try to remove `this` before id

```
<span class="nav-link btn btn-white btn-animate" id="{{prov.provname}}" (click)="getProvCustomers(id)">{{prov.provname}}</span>
```

2. Assuming you want to set the id as `prov.provname`

Add prov.provname in method param in View as @Emilien suggested

```
<span class="nav-link btn btn-white btn-animate" id="{{prov.provname}}" (click)="getProvCustomers(prov.provname)">{{prov.provname}}</span>
```